# Download/Save file that is obtainable directly from the given URL

Tags: java, download

I have got links like [this link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sachin_Tendulkar>&format=text%2Fcsv), which directly ask for the filename to save with, and start downloading in the browser.

How can I download or save this file programmatically?

I tried with the following method:

```
static void DownloadFile(String url, String fileName) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+<"+ url +">&format=text%2Fcsv";
    URL link = new URL(url); //The file that you want to download

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
    {
       out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

but this save the file having only the first line as ""subject","predicate","object"
" and not the complete file.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in an answer I tried the following, but that too gave only the first line of the file:

```
static void DownloadFile(String s_url, String fileName) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    s_url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+<"+ s_url +">&format=text%2Fcsv";
    //url = "http://dbpedia.org/data/Sachin_Tendulkar.rdf";
    try {   
        URL url = new URL(s_url); //The file that you want to download

        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with Apache FileUtils too, but that too gave only the first line of the file.

```
static void DownloadFile(String s_url, String fileName) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    s_url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+<"+ s_url +">&format=text%2Fcsv";
    URL url = new URL(s_url); //The file that you want to download
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(fileName));
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to download a file, Apache Commons have just what you are looking for, works great!

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("URL")), new File("path/to/file"));
```

if the url returns text, you can try something like this:

```
 try {   
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80/");

        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: No, it too gave only the first line of the file.

Comment: Can you give me a real sample of the link?

Comment: Sure, please visit this link: 
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Sachin_Tendulkar%3E&format=text%2Fcsv

Comment: I tried with the Apache Commons FileUtils, but that too gave only the first line of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65426/discussion-between-gurey-and-bit-manipulator).

Comment: Sorry for late response. Just sent you a message.